# Unique over multiple columns doesn't get checked

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to have a table schema where two columns share the same pool of values. For example a table with two columns `foo` and `bar` which contain integers shouldn't have the same number twice in both columns. It does work with only one column (`CREATE TABLE test (foo INT UNIQUE);`) but not with multiple columns.

For example I have the following SQL statements, all except the first should fail, because they use integers which are already present in one of the two columns:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (foo INTEGER NOT NULL , bar INTEGER DEFAULT NULL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES(42, 47);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES(47, 42);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES(47, 74);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test(foo) VALUES(42);
```

Marking two columns unique doesn't work for me, as this only checks if the combination of both values is already present (so only the third insertions fails).

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (foo INTEGER NOT NULL , bar INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, UNIQUE(foo, bar));
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES(42, 47);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES(47, 42);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES(42, 47);
Error: columns foo, bar are not unique
sqlite> INSERT INTO test(foo) VALUES(42);
```

Marking each column unique doesn't help either, as both columns should share the same pool of values.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (foo INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, bar INTEGER DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES (42, 47);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES (42, 47);
Error: column bar is not unique
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES (42, 74);
Error: column foo is not unique
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES (47, 42);
```

This is closer to my target than the combined version because it fails with the third insertion, but it is not exactly what I need.

I'm asking for this, because I want to save the numbers of hardware ports. And each line has at least one output port but can also have an input port. And obviously one port can't be both.

Comment: You are correct, I fixed my original post.

Comment: OK. Now question two: Should `INSERT INTO test VALUES(42, 47);` and `INSERT INTO test VALUES(48, 42);` succeed? (or the first only but the second fail)?

Comment: The second should fail, because 42 was already added (but just not in the second column which is the problem here).

Comment: You can't do what you want to do, other than adding a single extra table with 1 column and a unique key, and then using a trigger on your main table to try to insert all the values into that other table as well. You can't make 1 unique constraint that makes sure that no value occurs more than once in a set of columns like you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) for this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER very_unique
BEFORE INSERT ON test
WHEN NEW.foo IN (SELECT foo FROM test)
  OR NEW.foo IN (SELECT bar FROM test)
  OR NEW.bar IN (SELECT foo FROM test)
  OR NEW.bar IN (SELECT bar FROM test)
  OR NEW.foo = NEW.bar
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'foo or bar not unique');
END;
```

If you put UNIQUE constraints on both columns, you need only two of the SELECT checks in the WHEN clause.

Comment: You also need to check `OR NEW.bar = NEW.foo`

Comment: This did look promissing, but somehow `OR` is interpreted as `AND` as I was able to add an entry where one number was already in the other column. (I've also added the = check)

Comment: @xZise The last INSERT succeeds because neither value is yet in the table. (The earlier INSERT that would have inserted `47` did fail.)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare each one as unique:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    foo INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    bar INTEGER DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Comment: That does work better than my current schema, but `foo` and `bar` share the same pool of numbers. I've updated my question to explain it better (hopefully).

Comment: @xZise . . . What is this mysterious pool of numbers?  Can you provide an example (in the question) of what that looks like?